# How to convert saved text file encoding to UTF8?

Tags: c#-4.0, encode

recently i saved a text file on my computer  but when i open it again i saw some strings like:

```
 "˜ÌÇí ÍÑÝã ÚÌíÈå¿"
```

now i want to know is it possible to reconvert it to the original text (UTF8)?

i try this codes but it doesn't works

```
  string tempStr="˜ÌÇí ÍÑÝã ÚÌíÈå¿"; 
  Encoding ANSI = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
  byte[] ansiBytes = ANSI.GetBytes(tempStr);
  byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(ANSI, Encoding.UTF8, ansiBytes);
  String utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```

Comment: some thing like "سلام به همگی" , Persian language like Arabic language

Comment: Try `string str2 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(tempStr));`

Comment: @motevallizadeh There was no UTF8 there.

Comment: @Xanatos , then what is it?

Comment: @motevallizadeh Instead of using the `"iso-8859-1"` try the 1252 (no quotes), like `string str2 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes‌​(tempStr))`... There should be small differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
string str = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(tempStr))
```

The string wasn't really decoded... Its `byte`s where simply "enlarged" to `char`, with something like:

```
byte[] bytes = ...
char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    chars[i] = bytes[i];
}
string str = new string(chars);
```

Now... This transformation is the same that is done by the codepage ISO-8859-1. So I could simply have done the reverse, or I could have used that codepage to do it for me, I selected the second one.

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(tempStr)
```

this gave me the original `byte[]`

Then I've done some tests and it seems that the text in the beginning wasn't UTF8, it was in [codepage 1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256), that is an arabic codepage. So I

```
string str = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetString(...);
```

The only thing, the `˜` doesn't seem to be part of the original string.

There is another possibility:

```
string str = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(tempStr));
```

The codepage 1252 is the codepage used in the USA and in a big part of Europe. If you have a Windows configured to English, there is a good chance it uses the 1252 as the default codepage. The result is slightly different than using the `iso-8859-1`